# VBA Excel - Distributing number

Tags: vba, loops, for-loop

So i want to loop through a range of cells and add 1 until the work total (500 in this example) has depleted, so basically it adds a 1 in each cell until it adds up to 500. However everytime i run this code, the actual amount comes up short (473 in this example). I know this is pretty basic, but I have a pretty basic brain. Is it something to do with the for loop completing 500 times, but not the for each loop? Here is some really bad code:

```
Sub dividerloop()

Dim rngAmount As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim worktotal As Range
Dim i As Long

Set rngAmount = Sheet1.Range("E4:E21")
Set worktotal = Sheet1.Range("G2")

'set loop from 1 to work total
'set loop between cells
For i = 1 To worktotal.Value
    If i < worktotal.Value Then
        For Each c In rngAmount
'add 1 to each cell and increment i by 1
            If i < worktotal.Value Then
                c.Value = c.Value + 1
                i = i + 1
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next c
    Else
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Here is a pic of the spreadsheet:

[image: spreadsheet image]

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you're essentially skipping one iteration of i for every time you fill every cell. See that 500 / 18 is actually 27 floored, and that's the work total you're losing.

To avoid this issue, for every cell, you should only increment i for every value assigned *after* the first cell. For example, you can replace the inner `For Each` loop with this:

```
For r = 1 To rngAmount.Cells.Count
    Set c = rngAmount.Cells(r)

    If i < worktotal.Value Then
        c.Value = c.Value + 1
        If r > 1 Then i = i + 1
    Else
        Exit For
    End If
Next r
```

EDIT: Here's a simpler and more readable loop for ya. It should replace your main loop.

```
i = worktotal.Value

While (i > 0)
    For Each c In rngAmount
        c.Value = c.Value + 1

        If i > 0 Then i = i - 1
        If i = 0 Then Exit For
    Next
Wend
```

Comment: Thanks DanL the 2nd loop really explained it well and now I understand. This is now working, thanks alot for your help!

Comment: Great! Please mark as answer if it solved your issue :-)